# Regex javascript match a function from string of functions

Tags: regex

I have this string:

> 0;for(var b=0;32>b;b++)if(a&1<<31-b)return b;return 32});Math.Fb=Math.clz32;var xa=Math.abs,Hb=Math.cos,Ib=Math.sin,Jb=Math.atan2,Oa=Math.ceil,vb=Math.floor,Kb=Math.pow,ub=Math.min,K=0,Fa=null,aa=null;c.addRunDependency=Da;c.removeRunDependency=Ea;c.preloadedImages={};c.preloadedAudios={};var J=null,M=[function(a){var b=new WebSocket(w(a));b.binaryType="arraybuffer";b.events=[];b.onopen=function(){b.events.push([2,0,0]);va()};b.onerror=function(){b.events.push([3,0,0]);va()};b.onclose=function(){b.events.push([4,0,0]);va()};b.onmessage=function(a){a=new Uint8Array(a.data);var c=A(a.length);ka(a,c);b.events.push([1,c,a.length]);va()};for(a=0;a>2]=a[1];p[d>>2]=a[2];return a[0]},function(a,b,d,c,e){n.g[a].clearRect(b,d,c,e)},function(a,b,d){a=n.g[a].canvas;p[b>>2]=a.width;p[d>>2]=a.height},function(a,b,d){a=n.g[a].canvas;a.width=b;a.height=d},function(a){n.g[a].save()},function(a,b,d){n.g[a].translate(b,d)},function(a,b,d){n.g[a].scale(b,d)},function(a){n.g[a].restore()},function(a,b,d,c){n.g[a].fillStyle="rgb("+b+", "+d+","+c+")"},function(a,b,d,c,e){n.g[a].fillRect(b,d,c,e)},function(a,b,c,e){n.g[a].strokeStyle="rgb("+b+" , "+c+" ,"+e+")"},function(a,b){n.g[a].globalAlpha=b},function(a){n.g[a].beginPath()},function(a,b,c){n.g[a].moveTo(b,c)},function(a,b,c){n.g[a].lineTo(b,c)},function(a){n.g[a].stroke()},function(a,b){n.g[a].rotate(b)},function(a,b,c,e){n.g[a].drawImage(n.g[b].canvas,c,e)},function(a){n.g[a].fill()},function(){var a=document.getEl

Using regex, how do I extract `function(a,b,d,c){n.g[a].fillStyle="rgb("+b+", "+d+","+c+")"}` from it?

This is the regex I have come up so far: `/function\((.*)\).*fillStyle.*?}/`

The problem with the regex above is that it selects all the way from the first `function` it found and not just the function I want.

Comment: Try [`/function\(([^()]*)\){[^{}]*fillStyle[^{}]*}/`](https://regex101.com/r/jN4kQ8/1). This regex will not allow `(` and `)` inside the function signature, and won't allow `{` and `}` inside the function body though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be no  `(` and `)` inside the function signature, and `{` and `}` inside the function body, you may use

```
/function\(([^()]*)\){[^{}]*fillStyle[^{}]*}/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN4kQ8/1)

The idea is that you can use negated character classes `[^()]` and `[^{}]` in order not to overflow function boundaries.

A safer regex will be the one that matches from `(` up to `){` and then from `{` up to `},`:

```
/function\(([^)]*(?:\)(?!{)[^)]*)*)\){[^f}]*(?:}(?!,)[^}f]*|f(?!illStyle)[^}f]*)*fillStyle[^}]*(?:}(?!,)[^}]*)*}/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN4kQ8/2)

The idea is to use an unrolled tempered greedy token, one is `[^)]*(?:\)(?!{)[^)]*)*` (to match up to `)}`), the second one is `[^f}]*(?:}(?!,)[^}f]*|f(?!illStyle)[^}f]*)*` to match all text that is not `},` and not `fillStyle`, and the third one is `[^}]*(?:}(?!,)[^}]*)*` to match all text that is not `},`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. It looks complicated and I need to read it a few more times to understand the whole thing, haha. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the second expression is difficult, but your task is not really nice for a regex. I just suggested an expression that is as accurate as can be. The string you have is a real mess, so, the regexp can't look any better if you need precision. The first one is rather easy to understand, I believe.